# Initializing Disk on Linux Machine via SSH using Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-12.04

This is the reference I used but Ubuntu has slight difference in details.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/tutorials/virtual-machine-from-gallery/

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.1 and trying to setup the data Disk that I inserted for MySQL.

I have already executed these commands in the process:

1. sudo grep SCSI /var/log/dmesg
2. Entered Password
3. sudo fdisk /dev/sdc - typed n then hit enter
4. Typed p for partition

This is where my question comes in. The Partition number on Ubuntu show:

---

Partition Number (1-4 Default 2)

The example says to hit 1 but when I use 1. I get a different response. Am I supposed to use the default or 1. This is where I am lost.

Any type of assitance would be appreciated.

---

Comment: I'd recommend using `parted` instead to initialize and partition the disk, here you have some things about it: http://www.ctheroux.com/2012/06/initializing-a-brand-new-disk-with-parted/

Answer (score 0):

It is asking you to chose a partition number. Default is 2 because there is a partition there already, otherwise default would be 1. Generally you want to use the next available partition index (default).